# Starting web programming in Java

Tags: java

I've been programming in PHP and ASP.NET for a while now. When doing PHP, I've always used XAMPP to test my websites. I'm wondering (since I'm learning Java) if there are equivalent services around?

Furthermore, I know this is sort of an open question, but how would you make a basic page in Java, just a basic 'Hello World' web page.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36089158/java-hello-world

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java hello world](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36089158/java-hello-world)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually still use XAMPP.  You just need to install tomcat.  Here is a great screen cast on how to do it: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TUV_jPdq7fc.

If your a mac user you can try MAMP (whcih I prefer) and follow http://blog.mirotin.net/22/tomcat-on-mamp-the-simple-way.  To get Tomcat going.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to learn about programming in JSP and Servelets. JSP s are kinda like php in that they emit html out.

Also the server would be tomcat.

It would be best if you download [Eclipse for EE developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/indigosr1). You can also try Netbeans. [a sample servelet](http://mainline.brynmawr.edu/~dkumar/JSP/)

Answer (score 0):

You may read about [servlets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet) which is the basis for web applications in Java. There are many web frameworks built on top of them.

Answer (score 0):

I always recommend [Grails](http://grails.org/) to anyone getting started with java/the web. It's more important to grasp the patterns, lifecycle, and working with requests and responses than learning the actual language. Learning Grails has got me from hobbyist developer to IT employee working with ATG - one of the most obscenely challenging web frameworks there are.

Grails includes everything you need to get started: local server, scaffolding (that's your ticket to Hello World), database access, dependency injection, the list goes on. It's built on top of Spring, Hibernate, Sitemesh, etc, which are all well-known and excellent frameworks that are being used in production.

Grails is written with Groovy, a language written on top of the JVM not far from Java.

Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

i seems to be new to the platform nd new to java but would like to suggest what i have gained till now that for developing a java page we can have any of the two servers downloaded(Weblogic or tomcat). weblogic is fully implementation of classes whereas tomcat has partial implementation. Then for the next step that we require is a source file(java file),and html file and a xml file and these all needs to be placed in a root directory as like the source file,html file and a folder named WEB-INF to be placed parallel.
Inside WEB-INF folder needs to create classes folder where our java class file will be kept.
then needs to create a .war file and deploy it over weblogic to get our desired page display.

thanks......