# Java hello world

Tags: java

I am new to java programming. I tried hello world program, but I got an error "**not a statement**". Whereas when I copy, paste the hello world program from the internet, my program compiled. This is the program I used. What is meant by "**not a statement**", please explain why I got this error and what is meant by it and what should I look for when I get this error in the future. Thanks!

```
public class hello
 {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
   System.out.println(“hello world”);
}
}
```

My errors:-

```
hello.java:8: error: illegal character: '\u201c'
       System.out.println(“hello world”);
                          ^
hello.java:8: error: ';' expected
       System.out.println(“hello world”);
                           ^
hello.java:8: error: illegal character: '\u201d'
       System.out.println(“hello world”);
                                         ^
hello.java:8: error: not a statement
       System.out.println(“hello world”);
                                 ^
4 errors
```

Comment: Wrong double quote character? Should be `"` and not `“` (maybe your editor changes it).

Comment: it's because you are using these weird quote characters, you have to use `"hello"`, not `“hello world”`

Comment: @Reimeus * you're.

Comment: Reason #284 not to use a word processor as an IDE.

Comment: this happen when you copy code from pdf books

Comment: @FastSnail but the implication of that is that the code is being typeset in the books with smart quotes. So, wouldn't that be confusing the readers of the books?

Comment: @AndyTurner umm i have experienced this problem lot of time.even yesterday .i think there is a problem with pdf.almost all books i read have this symbol . for example now i'm reading "professional javascript for developers  " and in every example i have to edit this quotes after copy to console . `var s1 = “2”;` copied from it

Comment: @FastSnail I wasn't doubting that you'd experienced it, I was expressing surprise that PDFs are typeset using them. It seems very dubious editorially to use them.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
System.out.println(“hello world”);
```

with

```
System.out.println("hello world");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a [Unicode Character 'RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK' (U+201D)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201d/index.htm)

```
System.out.println(“hello world”);
```

replace them with the correct ones **"**

```
System.out.println("hello world");
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you copied and pasted the code from some where.It is copied with the unicode character that java do not support . Delete the line and try writing the code again and this will surely work

Answer (score 0):

When you copy and paste you the double quotes have to be changed since the unicode character is not supported by the IDE. 
Remove the double quotes and add it again in the IDE

```
System.out.println("hello world");
```